# What if you don't need a parameter when querying with Dapper?

Tags: dapper

I have one query that does a count/group by where I don't need a parameter (there is no where clause).

What is the syntax to run a parameterless query with dapper?

```
var _results = _conn.Query<strongType>("Select Count(columnA) as aCount, ColumnB, ColumnC from mytable group by ColumnB, ColumnC");
```

does not work.

I've tried it a few different ways but I still keep getting "ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code".

Tried to figure it out myself, searched all over and I'm giving up. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Below is the line of code from SqlMapper.cs that throws the error. It's line 1334

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(T).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null));
```

The error details: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: con

Comment: `_conn.Query<int>("Select Count(columnA) from mytable group by columnB")` Works fine for me...

Comment: what version of dapper are you on? I keep getting the null exception.

Comment: I used the latest version from google code... http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs

Comment: what does your sample query return when you run it in query analyzer?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I'm on the latest version. I currently have dapper as a project inside my solution. The project using it has a Referrence to Dapper. The Dapper referrence states it is version 1.6.0.0. A couple of days ago, I performed a pull from google code along with an update. I even tried removing and adding back the reference. Sam - the query works fine in query analyzer, it also works fine if I add in a parameter (ie var results = _conn.query<int>("Select count(columnA) from mytable where columnB = @param group by columnB", new {@param = param});

Comment: if it is 1000 are any of the results null?

Comment: very smart Sam!! There is a record with a Null. I could have helped by writting my question better. -1 for me. I'll fix the question.

Comment: ok, eliminated the nulls from the result set. Still getting the error. I've added more details to the question to help clarify.

Comment: can you break this into something simpler ... can you get `cnn.Query<int>("select 1 union all select 2");` to work? why is that working and not your result set?

Comment: did you have a non default constructor on your type?

Answer (score 4):

Mapping a single result back works just fine:

```
var a = cnn.Query<int>("select 1").Single()
// a is 1
```

You may face trouble if somehow your query returns no results, for example:

```
select count(Id) from 
(
select top 0 1 as Id, 2 as Title
) as X
group by Title
```

return 0 results, so doing a `Single` on an empty result set is not going to work.

Comment: The result set is more than one record. It is 1000's. See my comment I just posted on the question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var _results = _conn.Query("Select columnB, Count(columnA) C from mytable group by columnB");

int ColumnB = ((int)_results[0].ColumnB);
int C = ((int)_results[0].C);
```

Comment: same problem. The problem is that I'm missing a parameter.

Comment: then check two things: you version of Dapper AND what the value of _conn is AND whether another query is executable right before this line

Answer (score 0):

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: con

This is error is thrown by several dynamic ORMs including Dappper, PetaPoco and Massive but it's usually the same problem: Make sure you're using the [Ignore] attribute on the properties you don't want to include. This includes properties inherited from base classes. The error is useless but that's what it means.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur because a property you're trying to set in your return object is **get-only**. Dapper, of course, requires being able to set all properties. You might consider having a separate database DTO object that then gets converted to your properly immutable domain object after reading from the database.

Change this:

```
public string MyProperty { get; }
```

to this:

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```